# Angular Material scrolling through the tabs clears axis in C3 chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, tabs, angular-material, c3.js

There is a [strange behavior](http://recordit.co/kLoNQnBeeN) on the graph when I open dialog and click on the next tab. The axis just disappear :/

I've defined graphs separately in two controllers and bind to the md-tabs:

```
<div class="md-padding" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak>
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-selected="selectedIndex">
            <md-tab label="Tab 1" aria-controls="Tab 1"><span flex=""></span>
                    <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="GraphCtrl" ng-cloak>
                <svg id="chart1" width="450" height="300"></svg>
            </div>
            </md-tab> 

            <md-tab label="Tab2" aria-controls="Tab 2"><span flex=""></span>
                <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="Graph2Ctrl" ng-cloak>
                <svg id="chart2" width="450" height="300"></svg>
            </div>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxRohHcCv7JwFg5wRi8x?p=preview) what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call the resize on tab select(why i think this is the issue, because if you resize your browser you will see the x/y scales come back!)

Something like this on tab select of Tab 1

```
$scope.chart_grid_lines.resize()//in reference to your plunk above
```

Something like this on tab select of tab 2

```
$scope.chart.resize()//in reference to your plunk above
```

Comment: You're right, axis come back if you take an action on a graph or in browser. How to call the resize on tab select? Do you mean by call in HTML (md-tabs tag)? I'm trying with calling resize() in setTimeout function as is on the [example](http://c3js.org/samples/api_resize.html), but it doesn't work - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4in0YRbAGaHslxyZiHmG?p=preview)

Comment: on tab select call $scope.chart.resize() i am not very goof in material so i dont know how to write the callback for tab select.

Comment: What about cases when chart is generated by an angular directive so that we don't have the chart stored in variable?